# Call a non-static method from no object using std::function

Tags: c++, object, callback, sfml

While doing some random-ish, weird-ish things to understand a little bit more C++ (just to say I'm still a newbie), I came across something I can't properly understand : I'm currently using SFML which provides a few methods to create and manage a window, namely this method to close it: `void sf::RenderWindow::close()`. It doesn't take any argument, and it can't be called directly but through an instantiated object.

```
sf::RenderWindow::close(); // error
```

My problem is the following code :

```
sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(800, 600), "test"); // added after edit

const std::function <void(sf::RenderWindow &)> callback(sf::RenderWindow::close);
// callback(); 
callback(window); // closes the window
```

I'm not sure to understand what's happening here as I'm not using any object... even anonymous at first sight... I guess...

If someone can enlighten me, I'd really appreciate it.

Thanks you.

**Edit:**

My mistake, yes there's an object.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>


int main()
{
      sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(800, 600), "test");

      const std::function <void(sf::RenderWindow &)> call(sf::RenderWindow::close);
      call(window);

      return 0;
}
```

Actually, I understand this as if it were sf::RenderWindow::close(window), similarly to metatables in lua I suppose.

Comment: Does that really compile? If it does, then I don't understand it either.

Comment: [Doesn't compile for me.](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b3ed9e3b6b26fdc7) If this example doesn't compile for you, then your question does not have enough detail.

Comment: Could you post the _real_ code? Cause as it stands, C++ can't magically find an instance of a class when it needs one but none is specified.

Comment: I recommend creating a [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I'll post a clear code in a moment.

Comment: Quick note: the only reason you can form it to look like `Class::function(instance)` is because `std::function` allows for that representation. Normally, you must call `instance.function()`, and that's still what `std::function` must do internally (though I imagine it looks more like `(instance.*storedMemberFunction)()`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's linked to the concept of [Callable](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/Callable):

Since the stored target of the `std::function` (i.e. `sf::RenderWindow::close`) is a pointer to member function and the first  argument (i.e. `window`) is a (reference to) an object of type `RenderWindow`, then the invocation of the function object is equivalent to `window.close()`.

You could also have written something along those lines:

```
std::function<void(sf::RenderWindow*)> call = &sf::RenderWindow::close;
call(&window);
```

Below a code sample that doesn't involve SFML:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

class Window {
public:
    void close() {std::cout << "close" << std::endl; }
};

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    Window w;

    std::function<void(Window&)> f = &Window::close;

    f(w);

    std::function<void(Window*)> g = &Window::close;

    g(&w);

    return 0;
}
```